# How to return Flux<String> in ServerResponse in WebFlux

Tags: mono, spring-webflux, flux

I have a Jdbc Layer which is returning Flux. While returning the data, the fromPublisher method, it's accepting other Serializable classes, but the method is not accepting Flux.

Approach 1

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getNames(final ServerRequest request) {
               Flux<String> strings = Flux.just("a", "b", "c"); 
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(fromPublisher(response), String.class);
    }
```

Above approach is returning abc combined as a Single String.

I tried this,

```
return ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(response), List.class);
```

I tried this aswell.

```
 Mono<List<String>> mono = response.collectList();
ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(fromPublisher(mono, String.class));
```

but this is also giving a Runtime error of

```
> body' should be an object, for reactive types use a variant specifying
> a publisher/producer and its related element type
```

[image]

Comment: Flux is a stream not a list, so if you want to return a stream just return the flux directly, or remove the ”fromPublisher”. If you want to return a list you do a `collectList` on the flux and place the resulting Mono straight into the `body`

Comment: I tried that aswell. Its still giving me an error.

Comment: Please dont say ”i tried that aswell” tried what? All i pointed out? I dont see all your trials i pointed out in the question above. Also, dont say ”its still giving me an error” what error? We cant help you if you dont show us what you do what you get. If you expect help then please put in some effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working.

```
Mono<List<String>> strings = Flux.just("a", "b", "c").collectList();
 
return strings.flatMap(string -> ServerResponse.ok()
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .bodyValue(string));
```

Answer (score 4):

Below is an example of how to send back a `Flux<String>` in the body of a response

```java
Flux<String> strings = Flux.just("a", "b", "c");
ServerResponse.ok().body(strings, String.class);
```

Comment: This is not returning as a list, Its returning abc as single string in the response body.

Comment: you didn't ask to return it as a list in your question. You asked to return a `Flux<String>` and this is how you do it

Comment: Oh, Okay. I meant it as List of Strings. my Bad.

Comment: did you find the correct method? I also want to return it like ["a","b","c']